# Pandas/matplotlib bar chart with colors defined by column

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, pandas

I am trying to make a bar chart in python, and color bars by a data frame column, this is exceedingly easy in R ggplot2, so I really do who not understand why it is so hard in matplotlib/pandas, I would like to understand how to do it and hopefully the logic as I assume it can't be hard after all

Here is an example of what I want.  I did in ggplot - all I want is to define the color using attributes in the data frame, the attribute can be the color string i.e. 'k','r' .. or a feature of the data say male/female, etc.
[image]

this is an example of code I tried  that works to generate the bars

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['a','b','c'],'value' : [1,2,3], 
                     'c' : ['b','r','b']})
data.plot('name','value',kind='bar')
```

but I want the color defined by column 'c'

but when I add color='c' then it does not work

```
data.plot('name','value',color='c',kind='bar',color='c')
```

I tried using plot.scatter as well and it did not work either

---- Update

I did some more work and this works more or less, I have yet to figure out how to properly align the labels, I still do to like why I have to have a numeric x axis, when it is really categorical (again ggplot2 deals with this on its own) - but ar least this can be done in code

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(range(len(data)),data['value'],width=.5,color=data['c'])
ax.set_xticks(range(len(data)))
ax.set_xticklabels( (data['name'] ))
```

Thanks as always

Comment: Can you post an example figure? It's *exceedingly* difficult to know what you want w/o a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
data.plot('name','value',color=['r', 'g', 'b'],kind='bar')
```

You can give any combination of colors as a list to the color argument. If there are more bars than number of colors, the colors will just recycle.

[image]

I can also strongly recommend the excellent brewer2mpl library. It provides aesthetically pleasing color choices. The code looks like this:

```
import brewer2mpl
bmap = brewer2mpl.get_map('Set2','qualitative',3,reverse=True)
colors = bmap.mpl_colors
data.plot('name','value',color=colors,kind='bar')
```

resulting in:

[image]

You can get brewer2mpl from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/brewer2mpl/1.4

Comment: thanks for the answer, and thanks for the brewer tip. However this solution does not work as I am not working with 3 data points (this was just an llustration) but with many more and hence I am defining them with code on the data frame - the idea really is to have most bars be one color and have a fee (maybe even one) in a different color. Is there a way to drive the colors based on the data? in R for example all one has to pass to ggplot is fill=desired_column and it does that - I would assume python would have similar functionality

Comment: thanks for the comment! and also for the update to your question!

Comment: Is there any way to use brewer to select specific colors that you want to utilize?

Comment: This solution used to work for me, but in my current pandas version (0.20.3) it's using the first color in my `color` list for all bars, and ignoring the other colors.  The op's solution based on `ax.bar()` still works.

Answer (score 0):

One way to mimic the R behaviour with fill=desired_column is to create a new 'color' column with valid color strings in it, like 'r','g','b' or hex values etc. This can be done by using the map method on your desired_column. Then you can use this inside your plotting line as color.

Here is an example for OP's case:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['a','b','c'],'value' : [1,2,3], 
                     'c' : ['b','r','b']})

# Create new color column with map()
data['color'] = data['c'].map(lambda x: 'r' if x == 'b' else 'b')

# Plot with the new column 'color' as color argument
data.plot('name','value',kind='bar', color=data['color'])
```

A version that might be a bit more readable if there are more different values in 'c' than just two might be to not use a one line if function, but do the following to get the new 'color' column.

```py
def let_to_color(let, col1, col2):
    if let == 'b':
        return col1
    elif let == 'r':
        return col2

data['color'] = data['c'].map(lambda x: let_to_color(x, '#ff5544', '#002211'))
```