# Change bar colors in pandas matplotlib bar chart by passing a list/tuple

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

There are several threads on this topic, but none of them seem to directly address my question. I would like to plot a bar chart from a pandas dataframe with a custom color scheme that does not rely on a map, e.g. use an arbitrary list of colors. It looks like I can pass a concatenated string with color shorthand names (first example below). When I use the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26793165/pandas-matplotlib-bar-chart-with-colors-defined-by-column), the first color is repeated (see second example below). There is a comment in that post which eludes to the same behavior I am observing. Of course, I could do this by setting the subplot, but I'm lazy and want to do it in one line. So, I'd like to use the final example where I pass in a list of hex codes and it works as expected. I'm using pandas versions >=0.24 and matplotlib versions >1.5. My questions are:

- Why does this happen?
- What am I doing wrong?
- Can I pass a list of colors?

---

```
pd.DataFrame( [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] ).plot( kind="bar", color="brgmk" )
```

[image]

```
pd.DataFrame( [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] ).plot( kind="bar", color=[ "b", "r", "g", "m", "k" ] )
```

[image]

```
pd.DataFrame( [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] ).plot( kind="bar", color=[ "#0000FF", "#FF0000", "#008000", "#FF00FF", "#000000" ] )
```

[image]

Comment: `pd.DataFrame( [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] )[0].plot( kind="bar", color=[ "#0000FF", "#FF0000", "#008000", "#FF00FF", "#000000" ] )` works for this case. Seems like the behavior has changed based on similar questions here on SO.

Comment: It also works if you transpose `.T` the dataframe.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney but the resulting chart isn't exactly the same.

Comment: @BigBen That's true. There's no space between the bars.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney, yep. Regardless, it does seem like the behavior has changed from previous versions of pandas, based on all the questions here I've looked at.

Comment: @BigBen So the issue seems to be whether you pass a dataframe or a series?

Comment: That *seems* to be the issue, yeah. I'm not sure I have enough info to thoroughly answer the question though.

Comment: The plot api is persnickety

Comment: That's one adjective for it haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When plotting a dataframe, the first color information is used for the first column, the second for the second column etc. Color information may be just one value that is then used for all rows of this column, or multiple values that are used one-by-one for each row of the column (repeated from the beginning if more rows than colors). See the following example:

```
pd.DataFrame( [[ 1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]] ).plot(kind="bar", color=[[ "b", "r", "g" ], "m"] )
```

[image]

So in your case you just need to put the list of color values in a list (specifically not a tuple):

```
pd.DataFrame( [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] ).plot( kind="bar", color=[[ "b", "r", "g", "m", "k" ]] )
```

or

```
pd.DataFrame( [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] ).plot( kind="bar", color=[[ "#0000FF", "#FF0000", "#008000", "#FF00FF", "#000000" ]] )
```

---

The first case in the OP (`color="brgmk"`) works as expected as pandas [internally puts the color string in a list](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2c3edaaaa0475841349659297039a606a72e9273/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py#L206-L212) ([strings are not considered list-like](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2c3edaaaa0475841349659297039a606a72e9273/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx#L956)).

Comment: I used this answer to get to my solution, but I needed a tweak: instead of doing color=[[ "#0000FF", "#FF0000", "#008000", "#FF00FF", "#000000" ]] I had to specify the column name and use: color={'colA': [ "#0000FF", "#FF0000", "#008000", "#FF00FF", "#000000" ]}