# Matplotlib and Pandas change colors of negative values

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, bar-chart

I would like to set the color of the negative values of my bar graph to 'deepskyblue' and keep the positive values 'crimson'. What is the best way to accomplish this? X-values of my csv file are latitude points and my Y-values are temperature anomalies. I also seem to be having an issue with my x-axis, as seen in my linked figure. It is plotting ticks for every latitude point from -90 to 90, which results in a lot of overlapping. I would like to have those in increments of 15, but I can't figure out how to do that.

EDIT: solved.

[image: Final Version]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import numpy as np

filename = "2015_tAnoms.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=',',header='infer')

figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 6), dpi=300, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

ax = plt.gca()

ax.set_facecolor((0,0,0))
ax.set_ylim([-1,3])

ax.grid(color='lightgray', alpha=0.6, which='major', axis='y', linestyle='-')


plt.bar(df['Latitude'],df['TempAnom'],color=np.where(df['TempAnom'] < 0, 'deepskyblue', 'crimson'))
plt.margins(x=0)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(-90,91,15))

plt.xlabel("Latitude")
plt.ylabel("Temperature Anomaly (°C)")
plt.title("2015 Temperature Anomalies by Latitude Band")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass color as series with different colors depending on `df['TempAnom'] < 0` condition:

```
plt.bar(
    df['Latitude'], df['TempAnom'],
    color=np.where(df['TempAnom'] < 0, 'deepskyblue', 'crimson'),
)

ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(-90, 91, 15))
```

Output:

[image: chart]

Comment: Great, that works. Any idea on how to increment the x-axis so it isn't plotting every latitude point from -90 to 90? An increment of 15 is what I would like to get.

Comment: You can probably add `xticks` parameter to `df.plot.bar`: `df.plot.bar(..., xticks=np.arange(-90, 90, 15))`

Comment: @ChrisTurnbull [MultipleLocator](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator).

Comment: That fixes the labels, but now the values are starting at 0 @perl

Comment: @ChrisTurnbull Right, it's bar chart, so a bit different... Try what Quang Hoang suggested with `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.MultipleLocator(15))`

Comment: That almost works. I think part of the problem is that my min x-value is -89, so it isn't starting from -90.

Comment: OK, let's try something different. Use `plt.bar` instead of `df.plot.bar`, and then we can set xticks directly. I've updated my answer with these changes

Comment: it didn't work for me (inside a jupyter notebook, perhaps it's the reason, or because I use `plot(kind="bar"..)`), because color is a list of colors for each _column_ and not each value of TempAnom. This answer and this comment saved me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62826624/change-bar-colors-in-pandas-matplotlib-bar-chart-by-passing-a-list-tuple#comment125853765_62832879
you can pass a dict with a list of colors for the given named column.

Comment: @marrco Yes, this question was about having a different color for different values of the same column (e.g. red for positive and blue for negative), so it's different problem